# Meteor: publish some user data

Tags: meteor

I want to publish some limited user information about my users, the idea is that the admin role of my web app can view the emailaddress and username (last one is in the profile data).

```
Meteor.publish("usersSpecificDataforAdmin", function () {
    return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {
        'profile': 1,
        'emails': 1,
        'roles': 1
    }});
```

});
I'm then subscribing to this in my router:

```
adminRoutes.route('/users', {
  name: 'adminUsersList',
  subscriptions: function (params, queryParams) {
    this.register('adminUsersList', Meteor.subscribe('usersSpecificDataforAdmin'));
  },
  action: function (params, queryParams) {
    BlazeLayout.render('layout_frontend', {
      top: 'menu',
      main: 'adminUsersList',
      footer: 'footer'
    });
  }
});
```

In the template, I'm using the following to display the email address of the user: '{{emails.address}}', but that doesn't work. I can display all other info.

I have following questions:

- how can I display the email address of the user in the template
- even when I don't add the password or services fields in the publishing, it is send to the client (doing Meteor.user()) is revealing all the info, including passwords etc, which is a security issue in my opinion. How can I disable the publication of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several things:

1. You don't need to include `_id` in the list of fields to be published, it is always included
2. You're publishing `allUserData` but your router code is subscribing to `usersAllforAdmin` which you're not showing code for. I suspect that publication is including `services`
3. Passwords are not stored anywhere in Meteor, only the [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) hash of the password is stored in `services`
4. `emails` is an array, you can't access it with `{{emails.address}}` in spacebars, instead use `{{emails.[0].address}}` [(reference)](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#dotted-helpers-with-numeric-indices)

Comment: Thanks. I made a mistake indeed in the original post. I have edited the original question to contain the proper code. Your suggestion for item 4 is indeed working. The only strange thing is that while 'profile:1', it does not show when I do 'Meteor.user()' in the browser but the template is showing it. When I remove the 'profile:1', the template does not show it.

Comment: You don't have a `waitOn` in your route, there can be a delay while the subscription is fetched. I would use `waitOn` instead of `subscriptions`